# Can't Manipulate GoogleMap by supportMapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

EDIT: To create a marker and add it to the map. This method is called after the map is called.

```
public void testDisplay(){
    // latitude and longitude
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;

    // create marker
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));

    // adding marker
    map.addMarker(marker);
}
```

I am developing a Java android Application that provides an itinerary. I implemented google maps. But I can't seem to manipulate the map (Add markers, move around, add location user etc.)

Here are my imports (Maybe I am importing a different library of the same type):

```
import android.content.Context;


import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.codexmalta.mytravelbuddy.R;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;  

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

Here is my methods that contains the lines to get the map and I am calling it from the onCreate():

```
SupportMapFragment fm = new SupportMapFragment();

public void getMapFragment(){
        fm = (SupportMapFragment)   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = fm.getMap();
        Log.e("getmapfragment0", "got map fragment");
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setMapType(map.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    }
```

I also checked for NULL on map and it shows me that map is not NULL.

The map does not even change to Satellite. The button to get current location does not show up. What can I do to fix this? I am lost and I need to present this application on January.

Comment: Have you download google play services library in your SDK? or Post your logcat for fast sloution

Comment: instead of **map.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE** use **GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE**

Comment: @kaushik yeah i realized about that mistake afterwards, fixed it and still it didn't work. And I can't really get LogCat because I am testing on my mobile device. Perhaps I can send you the whole project and you change to your debug key and test it yourself?

Comment: You can still get LogCat trace if you connect your device to the computer. Are you getting any error or your map is loading correctly except for the MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE part? Is the map showing you your location?

Comment: have you add google play lib into your project??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

Activity must be `FragmentActivity`

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap mMap = fm.getMap();
```

For adding `marker`

```
Marker mapPinPoint = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

call`testDisplay()` after `initialize the map` from `onCreate`

Comment: I did this. It made my map update to Satellite view or whatever it is. But I still can't manipulate the map by adding markers or animations.

Comment: I will try it when I arrive home and will let you know if it works.